# Error displaying MLflow Artifacts in the MLFlow UI

Tags: mlflow

Summary:
Error displaying MLflow artifacts in the UI.

Description:
I have MLflow running on an [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) cluster on AWS with the artifact store set to [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) and backend to [RDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Relational_Database_Service) Aurora Cluster.

Everything is working fine. We can run models and these models' data does get posted to the S3 bucket which has both read and write access via [IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html) permissions.

So this is my error in the UI.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG4jR.png)

Additional information:

1. In this environment with the error - we recently upgraded MLflow from v1.26.0 to v2.2.1, but it is worth noting that the feature to view the artefacts within the UI never worked previously.
2. With [IaC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) I have spun up the same AWS EKS Cluster, with the same AWS IAM permissions and AWS RDS Aurora (albeit a clean fresh RDS) in a different account with MLflow v2.2.1 and once the engineers started running models and generating artifacts everything was working - even the MLflow UI feature of viewing the artifacts.

What I've tried:

1. I've looked at the tracking server CLI commands and ensured that the pod spun up using the --serve-artifacts option within the following command:

   ```
   mlflow server
       --port $MLFLOW_PORT
       --host $MLFLOW_HOST
       --backend-store-uri $MLFLOW_DB_CONN
       --default-artifact-root $MLFLOW_ARTIFACT_ROOT
       --gunicorn-opts "--log-level $MLFLOW_LOG_LEVEL"
       --serve-artifacts
   ```

   I even went as far as to include the registry store URI in a separate test as running 'mlflow doctor' indicated that the two MLflow applications on the two EKS Clusters had different directories:

   ```
   mlflow server
       --port $MLFLOW_PORT
       --host $MLFLOW_HOST
       --backend-store-uri $MLFLOW_DB_CONN
       --default-artifact-root $MLFLOW_ARTIFACT_ROOT
       --gunicorn-opts "--log-level $MLFLOW_LOG_LEVEL"
       --serve-artifacts
       --registry-store-uri file:///mlruns
   ```
2. I've went through all the AWS IAM policies - they are nearly identical except for environment specific references.

At this point I'm still having the same error and I have a hunch that MLflow v1.26.0 brought with a nearly invisible setting (when upgrading to v2.2.1) that may be stored within the AWS RDS.

Comment: This may be borderline, but consider [transcribing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76310254/edit) the error message. See also *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*). (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: What is the artifact location of the experiment `mlflow_pyspark_scorer`?